# Unique results for each column in 1 table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique, distinct, sql-server-2014

Using SQL Server 2014, I have a really big table where I need to get something like list of unique items of each column, I don't need regard between each other. The same like if I will distinct each column in different tables. But i need to get result  in one table.

Example of initial data:

```
 Project   | Status    | Employees |
 -----------------------------------
 Project 1 |   Active  |     10    |  
 Project 2 |   Closed  |     10    | 
 Project 3 |   Closed  |     20    | 
 Project 1 |   Active  |     20    | 
 Project 2 |   Closed  |     20    |
```

Requested data, where I need to get only unique results of each column.

```
 Project   | Status    | Employees | 
 -----------------------------------
 Project 1 |   Active  |     10    |  
 Project 2 |   Closed  |     20    | 
 Project 3 |           |           | 
           |           |           |
```

If it is possible hope for help with syntax.

Comment: Is this not simply using `GROUP BY` and `SUM` in your query? What have you tried so far to achieve your aim?

Comment: It's possible using a separate Select on each column doing a GROUP BY/DISTINCT and a ROW_NUMBER. And then all those Selects must be Full Outer Joined. Of course that would be a really big overhead on a *"really big table"*. But why do you want a result like that? It's not a table, it's just a bunch of non-related values.

Comment: I need to get these results for filter data in ssrs report. If its not hard for you, plz make and example of your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pain, because the result set is not in relational form:  the columns in each row are not related to each other.  But, you can do it, by using `row_number()` and either a `full outer join` or aggregation:

```
select p.project, s.status, e.employees
from (select project, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
      group by project
     ) p full outer join
     (select status, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
      group by status
     ) s
     on p.seqnum = s.seqnum full outer join
     (select employees, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
      group by project
     ) e
     on e.seqnum = coalesce(p.seqnum, s.seqnum);
```